# Como faço para alterar uma linha em um arquivo de dados de forma iterada em Python?

Tags: python, data.frame, dataset

Opa! Estou tentando criar um script em Python que lê um arquivo de dados externo, que possui várias linhas e diferentes números colunas. O script que criei segue abaixo:`

```
import numpy as np

entrada = open('dados.dat', 'r')
lista_de_linhas = entrada.readlines()
valor = int(52)
if (lista_de_linhas[72]):
    j=0
    comprimento = len(lista_de_linhas[72])
    print comprimento
    for j in range( 0, (comprimento) ):
        fsaida=open('dados_%i.dat' % (j+1), 'w')
        i = 0
        while i in range( 0, (comprimento) ):
            if (j==i):
                fsaida.write ('%f' % valor)
            else:
                fsaida.write ('%f' % 0)
            break
```

O script lê todo o arquivo de entrada. Queria fazer uma alteração na linha 72 desse arquivo que é uma linha dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu queria que o script gerasse, para cada arquivo de saida, uma linha 72 com um valor 52 e o restante dos valores todos iguais a zero. Por exemplo: o arquivo de saida 1, deveria ter o primeiro valor da coluna igual a 52 e o restante todos nulo. O segundo arquivo de dados deveria ter o segundo valor igual a 52 e o restante nulo e assim por diante. Mas não estou conseguindo fazer o script iterar as colunas. Alguém pode me ajudar???

Comment: Iae, colega! O ideal é vc [edit] a pergunta e postar seu código como texto. Assim não dá pra reproduzir. ;)

Comment: Para começar, edite a pergunta e coloque o código no corpo do texto para ser possível copiar e colar. Outra coisa: saber como esse dado está salvo dentro do arquivo `dados.dat` é essencial para ajudá-lo.

Comment: Opa! Vou fazer isso. Valeu!!

Comment: Alterado pessoal!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode e deve utilizar a função `iteritems();`

Dessa forma:

```
for x, y in lista_de_linhas.iteritems():
```

Depois só seguir sua lógica.

[Python - Iteritems()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems)

Comment: Oi Rafael. Não deu certo. Aparece este erro:  File "leitor2.py", line 11, in <module>
    for index, j in lista_de_linhas.itertems():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'itertems' 
Porque será? Será por causa das váriaveis dos índices?

Comment: qual versão do python você está utilizando? @FlavioRusch

Comment: Versão 2.7.6 Rafael.

Comment: tente lista_de_linhas.items()

Comment: Da o mesmo erro. Uma pergunta: nessa linha de comando o x o índice inicial e y o valor a ser iterado pela função iteritem()? Eu pesquisei sobre essa função mas não encontrei muita coisa.